# Unity - What changes to a game object trigger baked lights to need a rebake?

Tags: unity, lighting

I've noticed that sometimes when I make changes to game objects in scenes that have baked lights that the baked shadows will no longer be in effect and dynamic lights will instead be showing.

Destroying and recreating the object seems to trigger this reliably, but what other changes to games objects in a scene can cause a rebake to be needed?

[image]